# How to implement DBContext in MVC4 application?

Tags: model-view-controller, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

Could someone please point me to a good tutorial on how to implement DBContext in MVC4 application.

Also please help me with the below questions:

1. Where is the data stored for applications with DbContext. Is there a physical database created or is it stored in the mdf file?
2. Does the data persist with the deployments. How does it work with the deployments?
3. I am thinking of using it to store user session related information in the DBContext as it is in this reference: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-multitenant-openidconnect. If we have multiple servers, How is this synchronized?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple really, if you search for entity framework with the word db context you will get result such as: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj729737.aspx

As stated in the following link, all you really need to create is a class that inherits from the db contexts ie:

```
public class ProductContext : DbContext 
{ 
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; } 
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; } 
}
```

Of course its varies depending if you implement code first approach where you will have to create your own context or map an existing database (database approach) where things get scaffold for you.

Now, next step will be to enable migrations once you created the class that inherits from entity framework db context class  and define data sets. So search for enabling migrations entity framework... this will provide you with enough result to continue.. and the database gets create for you and gets stored in app data folder as two files mdf and ldf.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Could you please answer the questions:1.Does the data persist with the deployments. How does it work with the deployments?
2.I am thinking of using it to store user session related information in the DBContext as it is in this reference: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-multitenant-openidconnect. If we have multiple servers, How is this synchronized?

Comment: Every time I deploy the site, does it wipe the data in the mdf and ldf files?